# cdot for scientific notation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, monkeypatching

I really would like to have consistently $\cdot$ instead of $\times$ for the scientific notation in matplotlib. In addition I would like to keep all of the default settings of the `matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter`, like the calculation of offsets. For this reason I cannot simply create a new formatter with `FuncFormatter` and alike.

In matplotlib 3.3.1 I solved this problem via inheritance from `ScalarFormatter`.

```py
class MyScalarFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    def _formatSciNotation(self, s):
        # transform 1e+004 into 1e4, for example
        if self._useLocale:
            decimal_point = locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']
            positive_sign = locale.localeconv()['positive_sign']
        else:
            decimal_point = '.'
            positive_sign = '+'
        tup = s.split('e')
        try:
            significand = tup[0].rstrip('0').rstrip(decimal_point)
            sign = tup[1][0].replace(positive_sign, '')
            exponent = tup[1][1:].lstrip('0')
            if self._useMathText or self._usetex:
                if significand == '1' and exponent != '':
                    # reformat 1x10^y as 10^y
                    significand = ''
                if exponent:
                    exponent = '10^{%s%s}' % (sign, exponent)
                if significand and exponent:
# Here is the only relevant change
                    return r'%s{\cdot}%s' % (significand, exponent)
                else:
                    return r'%s%s' % (significand, exponent)
            else:
                s = ('%se%s%s' % (significand, sign, exponent)).rstrip('e')
                return s
        except IndexError:
            return s
```

and then passing

```py
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(MyScalarFormatter())
```

whenever I like.
This worked reliably until new versions of matplotlib came up. Of course I can monkey patch again, but what is a portable and reliable way of achieving the same result in matplotlib>=3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your previous solution. It seems as though it is still hardcoded into the function that creates the text and as of now can only be solved by inheriting from `ScalarFormatter`. This is the monkey patch that works for me using version 3.8.1.

```
class MyScalarFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    def get_offset(self):
        if len(self.locs) == 0:
            return ''
        if self.orderOfMagnitude or self.offset:
            offsetStr = ''
            sciNotStr = ''
            if self.offset:
                offsetStr = self.format_data(self.offset)
                if self.offset > 0:
                    offsetStr = '+' + offsetStr
            if self.orderOfMagnitude:
                if self._usetex or self._useMathText:
                    sciNotStr = self.format_data(10 ** self.orderOfMagnitude)
                else:
                    sciNotStr = '1e%d' % self.orderOfMagnitude
            if self._useMathText or self._usetex:
                if sciNotStr != '':
                    # only relevant change
                    sciNotStr = r'\cdot\mathdefault{%s}' % sciNotStr
                s = fr'${sciNotStr}\mathdefault{{{offsetStr}}}$'
            else:
                s = ''.join((sciNotStr, offsetStr))
            return self.fix_minus(s)
        return ''
```